# How much DME do you use for a 5 gal. batch?

Tags: extract, dme

I'd also like to add Dark Egyptian Cane Sugar (to a porter), and Honey (to a nut-brown ale). Amounts of these? Add during boil? Goal is 5 - 7% alcohol content.  Thanks!

Comment: We can't answer that without the estimated OG of the porter and brown ale. Find a recipe calculator there's many apps and websites, that will estimate all types of fermentables for a desired ABV

Comment: I don't see how the title fits the question text. You may get better answers if the title matches the question.

Answer (score 2):

DMe has about 45 ppg.  That's points per lb. per gal.  So one lb. of DME in one gal. of water yields a gravity of 1.045.  Divide by 5 for 5 gal. and you get 1.009.  So, in a 5 gal. batch, you get 9 gravity points out of 1 lb. of DME.  5 lb. in 5 gal. will get you 1.045 OG.  Cane sugar has about the same ppg.  Honey is around 32 ppg.  Using all of that, if you know the gravity you're going for, you can figure out how much of what to use.